# How do display modes work?

Tags: graphics-card, display

It seems to be the case that a typical display will come with a variety of display modes (different resolutions/refresh rates).

Given that modern displays (LED etc) will have physical pixels, and therefore a pre-defined 'native' resolution, how do other resolutions work? Is there some sort of re-sampling in order to support resolutions that aren't integer divisions of the native resolution? Does this happen within the display itself, or within the GPU?

Finally, what's the point of different display modes? Is it just a matter of convenience for developers who wish to use resolutions other than the native resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some sort of re-sampling in order to support resolutions that aren't integer divisions of the native resolution?

Yep.  The operation the LCD does is called "scaling" or "interpolation".  This [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_resolution) article provides more details.

> Does this happen within the display itself, or within the GPU?

If the display is receiving a lower resolution than its native, the display is doing the resampling, not the GPU.

> Finally, what's the point of different display modes?

These were more probably more important in the older days of PCs.

The original IBM PC had 2 different graphics cards, an MDA adapter which supported text mode, and a CGA adapter which supported MDA's text mode or two graphics modes - a 320x200 mode that supported 4 colors, or a 640x200 bitmap mode that supported 1 color.

So you selected the proper mode according to whether number of colors or higher resolution was more important.  Text mode worked very differently than graphic mode.  This is before VGA or modern GPUs.

Other graphics cards like Hercules and EGA then were developed, and these added more modes with more capabilities - but they also required more video RAM, which may or may not be present.  The old modes were still available for compatibility and if speed was desired over appearance.

Now everything is pretty much 24-bit truecolor and fast enough where resolution doesn't matter as much - but it still may in some instances.

It's faster to update 1920x1080 pixels than 4K pixels, and if software rendering is being used instead of GPU rendering (like some emulators), the speed may still be affected even on more modern hardware.

I do have an older laptop from the late 2000's that struggles with rendering on a 4K television at its native resolution, versus the 1920x1080 of the laptop LCD.  But newer platforms and GPUs can probably handle it with a breeze.